# Calling a REST API function onPress

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-native

I have this REST API function here that i'd like to call once I press the button below (so the data gets sent to the server)

```
async function flaskAPI() {
    try {
        await fetch('https://webhook.site/10d127c0-79b5-42e7-86c3-0badd9b58f4f', {
            method: 'post',
            mode:'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: pickerSel
            })
        });
    }   catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

This is the button that I would press. I want it to call the API function **AND** take me to the next screen on press. Can this be done?

```
<Button icon='arrow-right' mode='outlined' color='black'
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Scanner')}                        
                        >
                            Dalje
                        </Button>
```

This is only a test REST API I'm trying out if you have any comment on it please you're more than welcome to post them

Comment: What's the actual issue you're having?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to include it in my `Button` component.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: Send it to a backend server

Comment: This helps you? https://codesandbox.io/s/async-await-with-fetch-ihl1l

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about your question but perhaps this helps?

If your function and the component is in the same class:

```
const flaskAPI = async (){
    try {
        await fetch('https://webhook.site/10d127c0-79b5-42e7-86c3-0badd9b58f4f', {
            method: 'post',
            mode:'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: pickerSel
            })
        });
    }   catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

THEN:

```
<Button onPress={flaskAPI}/>
```

If you want to navigate to the "Scanner" screen, you can include the following to your flaskAPI function.

```
navigation.navigate("Scanner");
```

Comment: You should post your class structure.